# How to make last <li> stick to footer of parent <ul> of specific height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to keep the last **li** fixed to bottom of parent **ul** that is of some specific height. But as soon as I try to scroll the part, The last element also starts moving.

```
    ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
    }
    li:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color: white;}
```

I have created a demo for this : JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/zrVPJ/2/

Comment: Use `position:fixed;` ?? :-)

Comment: Yeah. But that will make it fixed respective to page and not to ul.

Comment: you can change last li positition:fixed instead of absolute...

Comment: Nikhil : Making it position fixed will be w.r.t to screen and not the ul. So If I add something above ul it will breakdown.

Answer (score 2):

try this one by editing your css.

```
li:last-child {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 22px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 127px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zrVPJ/3/)

Comment: I love that the answer was in the question ;-)

Comment: Good trick. But that last li is taking position fixed from top of page and not the ul. So if I add anything above ul. will keep the header misplaced.

Comment: u can also change `ul { position: static; }` and `li:last-child { position:absolute; }` [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zrVPJ/5/)

Answer (score 1):

#### Figured I'd clarify further.

There are two major differences between `position:fixed` and `position:absolute`;

**Absolute** takes your `document` properties, while **fixed** takes your `window` properties.

If you need something to stay somewhere, a sidebar, a `fixed` cell, utilize **fixed**.

If you need to position something around your **DOM** specifically, utilize **absolute**.

There are several tricks to using **absolute**. One being **relative** and one being **static**. By using **static** on your `ul`, then classifying the `last-child` to reflect that, you're keeping the ul in place, but the **absolute positioning** of your final cell is running against its parents properties.

**Read more:**

#### http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp