# In an ul element of long Height how to have two element in bottom

Tags: html, css

I have an simple `ul` element which have large height, I want last two `li` elements on the bottom of `ul` element and rest on top.

You can see the current implementation [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mimani/x7ve4wv0/).

Code is like this:

```css
.my-ul {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <ul class="my-ul">
    <li>First Element</li>
    <li>Second Element</li>
    <li>Third Element</li>
    <li>Fourth Element</li>
    <li>Fifth Element</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510401/how-can-i-positioning-li-elements-to-the-bottom-of-ul-list) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21249667/1610034), but these are [not working](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mimani/x7ve4wv0/1/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution I see here is flexbox

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

ul li:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>first</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css selector for last two Elements.See the example code  below:

```
<div id="demo">
  <ul class="my-ul">
    <li>First Element</li>
    <li>Second Element</li>
    <li>Third Element</li>
    <li>Fourth Element</li>
    <li>Fifth Element</li>
  </ul>
</div>

.my-ul {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: grey;
}
li:last-child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 370px;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  position: fixed;
  top: 350px;
}
```

Comment: `nth-last-child` would be better, since you may not be sure how many list items there are.

Comment: Yes , It is more correct to use `nth-last-child` for larger list of items.